# Shortcuts for arrow syntax

Tags: javascript

I am used to the following arrow syntax:

```
(var1, var2, var3) => {
    statement1;
    statement2;
    ...
}
```

However, I've also seen it simplified to just:

```
var1 => something
```

What are the rules for when the arrow statement can be simplified. Specifically:

- Not need parens before the `=>`?
- Not need `{` ... `}` around the function body?

Comment: When used without curly brackets, the function implicit returns.